# Wordpress site switched to displaying Posts for no apparent reason

Tags: wordpress

I have a site with a static home page which is just one of the pages.  Ive been working on the site for several weeks. Today, when I went to clear the cache to see if some links were updated, the home  page switched to displaying Posts (which is the other setting under the Settings->Reading) I went to settings and sure enough display Posts is checked. No one else, that I know of has the password to this site. Does anyone know why this happened or how I can prevent it from happeneing again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many variables to consider, but it has to be a direct database manipulation. So:

- Someone did in fact change it, but no one knows who
- A plugin or theme changed it. Unlikely, but certainly possible. Search your plugins/theme changelog and/or support threads for similar reported issues

One thing you could do is install the plugin Stream. This logs all (well, nearly every) database manipulation and tells you when, where, and who. This way, if it happens again, you can immediately pinpoint it.